# Choose value in column depending on a second column

Tags: python, pandas

I have some DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Food': ['pizza', 'pasta', 'pizza'], 'Day': [3, 4, 5], 'Time': [8,9,10]})
```

I would like to add a new column, `NEW` that selects the `Day` if the `Food` is *pizza* or the `Time` if the `Food` is *pasta*, e.g.:

[image]

Comment: What happens if `Food` is neither?

Comment: Then I get hungry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use `np.where`

```
df['New']=np.where(df.Food=='pizza',df.Day,df.Time)
```

Comment: @TipsyHyena check with np.select

Answer (score 1):

Or `loc`:

```
df['NEW'] = df['Day']
df.loc[df['Food'].eq('pasta'), 'NEW'] = df['Time']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Day   Food  Time  NEW
0    3  pizza     8    3
1    4  pasta     9    9
2    5  pizza    10    5
```